# How to disable maximize,mimimize and close button for a new window open

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.open()` method to open a page as a pop-up window for a link button click event.
But the poup-up window is having minimize,maximize,close(x) button.

I dont want those buttons. How can remove these buttons?

This is the method i am using,

```
window.open(url,"Link","toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,titlebar=no,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width=450,height=310,left=500,top=350");
```

Tell me how can do this.

Regards,
Chirag Jain.

Comment: Think about how would you feel if someone pops up a window in your browser and you can't close it.

Comment: @Vatev 

Think about a scenario where the user is paying using credit card and want to prevent accidental closure of the window

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If you want a popup *style* window without full window decorations you'd have to create a new overlay `<div>` on top of the existing content and fill that with content, perhaps using an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Agreed. Popup windows... right up there with ironing and hanging washing outside to dry i.e. things you can't believe are still done in 2012.

Comment: Next up: using JS to disable right-clicking so you can't copy/paste text. Oh, and one of those "copying this text is prohibited" popups. :(

Comment: haha yes. They always used to make me laugh. Obviously never heard of "view source code".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from javascript alone. Think about it, if you could, then people could put it into code on web-pages and cause other people's computers to open windows they couldn't easily close.

Instead you'll have to look for an answer specific to whichever browser you're using to host this application, and change it on the computers of your users appropriately. Even then though I don't think you'll be in luck (with Firefox for example, I can see how to get rid of them on all browser windows, but not on just one).